# httaccess change mydomain.com/knowledgebase.php to mydomain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I checked many other similar questions but I can't come up with a .htaccess rule that would work properly.

I have a server containing a Knowledgebase system (knowledgebase.php). I don't want to show this `knowledgebase.php` in the URL, ever.

Examples what I want:

- https://help.thecrypto.app should show same url (now it shows https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php when you visit)
- https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php?article=1 should show URL https://help.thecrypto.app/?article=1

How can I do this?

I tried many options, including this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /knowledgebase.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: So you mean link `https://help.thecrypto.app` should be served by `https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php?article=1`? Could you please do mention these URLs from which url to you want to redirect.

Comment: So now https://help.thecrypto.app by default always opens `https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php`, which is OK (this server only contains knowledgebase system). But I want to hide `knowledgebase.php`. So if you visit `https://help.thecrypto.app` url should stay the same, not  change to `https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php`. And whe nn you click on any link in knowledgebase, url should not be `https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php?article=1` but `https://help.thecrypto.app/?article=1 `.

Comment: Do you any error with the code you have tried ?

Comment: Yes, it's not working. You can try to visit https://help.thecrypto.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1) redirect "help.thecrypto.app/" to /knowledgebase.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help.thecrypto.app$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase\.php$ / [L,R]
#2) internally map knowledgebase.php to the root /
 RewriteRule ^/?$ /knowledgebase.php [END]
```

This will serve `/knowledgebase.php` if you visit your site hompage `/` .

Comment: Actually, I don't want to ever show the "knowledgebase.php" part in the url. So if you visit https://help.thecrypto.app, the url should stay the same (try it, now it will show `https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php` when you visit it). And this happens without any rewrite rules.

Comment: @PrimozKralj This does not change your URL.

Comment: I tried it, it works! Sorry, I thought based on checking your code it will not work. But it does :)

Comment: @PrimozKralj Sorry the code is incomplete as it does not manipulate your other  URLs with querystring forexample `knowledgebase.php?article=1` is still the same. will update the code within a few minutes.

Comment: But it does seem to work properly for me. If I visit https://help.thecrypto.app/knowledgebase.php?article=1, the shown URL is `https://help.thecrypto.app/?article=1` which is OK. Or maybe you though about something else?

Comment: @PrimizKralj  Yes it does handle those URLs too. thanks.

Comment: One thing I've noticed now is that SSL certificate now seems to be broken. How to fix this? Please see http://prntscr.com/vzvouf

Comment: @PrimožKralj  This rule doesn't conflict your SSL redirection .I just visted your URL.  The C loud Flare  SSL redirection seems to be okay.

Comment: You are right. It must have been issue with an image on that page, using http instead of https. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before testing urls.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewritewriteRule ^ knowledgebase.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(knowledgebase) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/?article=1 [L]
```

Comment: Sadly it gives me "Internal Server Error".

Comment: @PrimožKralj, ok I have added 1 more condition, could you please check it now and let me know. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing these.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it still produces same error.

Comment: @PrimožKralj, kindly do let me know by hitting which url you are getting error?

Comment: By hitting "https://help.thecrypto.app". I have now removed these conditions so right now it will not produce the error though.

Comment: @PrimožKralj, what these urls should take care of is, 1- `http://localhost:80/` to `http://localhost:80/knowledgebase.php`, 2nd- From url `http://localhost:80/knowledgebase/` to `http://localhost:80/?article=1`. Kindly do let me know if this is not working this way please.

Comment: I highly appreciate your input, thank you. I was able to solve this with this answer from @Amit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65215322/1181261